# How to erase lines with nothing in second column in bash?

Tags: bash, curl

This is a sample output of `curl -s ifconfig.me/all | column -t`:

```
ip_addr:      193.136.19.55
remote_host:  gwec.di.uminho.pt
user_agent:   curl/7.22.0        (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)  libcurl/7.22.0  OpenSSL/1.0.1  zlib/1.2.3.4  libidn/1.23  librtmp/2.3
port:         37429
lang:
connection:
keep_alive:
encoding:
mime:         */*
charset:
via:
forwarded:
```

I like to parse this in such a way that the *user_agent* field doesn't get tabs, and erase all fields with no results.

```
ip_addr:      193.136.19.55
remote_host:  gwec.di.uminho.pt
user_agent:   curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
port:         37429
mime:         */*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}NF>1{t=$1;$1="";printf "%-13s%s\n",t,$0}'
```

Output with the sample input:

```
ip_addr:      193.136.19.55
remote_host:  gwec.di.uminho.pt
user_agent:   curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
port:         37429
mime:         */*
```

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect! Can you explain the input?

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` you can use `awk '$2'`, that will check whether the 2nd field exists or not. If it does exist, the line will be printed.

In your case,

```
curl -s ifconfig.me/all | column -t | awk '$2'
```

#### Example

```
$ awk '$2' your_result
ip_addr:      193.136.19.55
remote_host:  gwec.di.uminho.pt
user_agent:   curl/7.22.0        (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)  libcurl/7.22.0  OpenSSL/1.0.1  zlib/1.2.3.4  libidn/1.23  librtmp/2.3
port:         37429
mime:         */*
```

---

> I like to parse this in such a way that the user_agent field doesn't
>   get tabs, and erase all fields with no results.

Use the input field separator (FS=tab) and output field separator (OFS=space) like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS=" "} $2 {printf "%s\t",$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf $i ; printf "\n"}' your_result
ip_addr:        193.136.19.55
remote_host:    gwec.di.uminho.pt
user_agent:     curl/7.22.0(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)libcurl/7.22.0OpenSSL/1.0.1zlib/1.2.3.4libidn/1.23librtmp/2.3
port:   37429
mime:   */*
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know a solution to the *user_agent* field?

Comment: It's better to use printf for aligned output. Also, using $2 to $8 is finite and may not include other fields if they are more than 8. Please see my post in which the concept seemed copied.

Comment: @konsolebox belive me I did not copy, I just saw your answer now. Anyway, I have updated my answer so it is different from yours. I did it with a `for` loop to get the same result.